# If universe was instead cosmological blueshifted, would we still notice dark energy?

Tags: space-expansion, dark-energy, cosmological-constant

Imagine instead of us seeing more distant galaxy turning redder, they now becomes more blue at a similar rate. This time round would we be able to notice those mythical dark energy? I suppose missing matter yes and Albert Einstein can certainly do away with the cosmological constant guilt free right?

Comment: Are you asking us to consider what we would conclude if the universe were _contracting_ instead of expanding? Or are you asking us to consider what we would conclude if the universe were still expanding but progressively more distant galaxies were more and more blueshifted? If it's the latter, what part of the laws of physics are you changing to allow for this? (For example, are we throwing out the concept of relativistic Doppler shift, and if so, what are we replacing it with?)

Comment: @probably_someone: suppose E. Hubble announced that he discovered the further the galaxy the bluer they are.

Comment: Ok, in that case, it really, really depends on the precise details of Hubble's data. Is the ratio of blueshift/distance constant, increasing, or decreasing with distance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If galaxies are blue shifted on a long range, it would mean that the universe as a whole is **contracting** *and* **decelerating**.

If galaxy $B$ is farther away than galaxy $A$, and more blue shifted, then it's moving in our direction at a greater velocity than A.  But since light takes more time to get to us with distance, it would mean $v_B > v_A$, at global universal time $t_B < t_A$.

This implies that there's a *repulsive force*, in addition to the attractive gravitational force, slowing down the contracting universe.  Thus yes, the blueshift increasing with distance would imply the existence of some "dark energy".

In the case of the normal redshift increasing with distance, the conclusion isn't the same.  Galaxy $B$ having a stronger redshift than $A$ while at a larger distance implies a larger velocity at time $t_B < t_A$.  Thus the universe is expanding (from the redshift) and slowing down too.  This deceleration may be caused by the attractive effect of gravity alone on the expanding universe, and doesn't necessarily imply the existence of dark energy.  It is the detailed analysis of the redshift and its *variation* with distance that may show there's a repulsion effect (which is very weak, in our universe).

Comment: A uniform contraction is a time reversed uniform expansion that does not imply any forces, acceleration or deceleration, or the existence of "dark energy".

Comment: @safesphere, I didn't talked about any uniform contraction / expansion.  I guess that this would be the special case of a dark energy balancing exactly the gravity attraction.  But then, the details should come out from the Friedman-Lemaître equations using the scale factor $a(t) = t$.